# Need to transform comma separated values into R data frame

Tags: r, transpose

> I have a data file (txt file) that looks like this:
> **input: trials.txt**
> Control 0.53, 0.36, 0.20, -0.37, -0.60, -0.64, -0.68, -1.27
> Knees 0.73, 0.31, 0.03, -0.29, -0.56, -0.96, -1.61
> Eyes -0.78, -0.86, -1.35, -1.48, -1.52, -2.04, -2.83
> Note: there is no comma after the first value in each row.

**Expected Output in data frame:**
Control Knees   Eyes
0.53    0.73    -0.78
0.36    0.31    -0.86
0.2     0.03    -1.35
-0.37   -0.29   -1.48
-0.6    -0.56   -1.52
-0.64   -0.96   -2.04
-0.68   -1.61   -2.83
-1.27

How do I do that using R?

Answer (score 2):

We may read the `.txt` file with `readLines` and then use `read.csv` after removing the initial word to read as data.frame making use of the delimiter `,`, `t`ranspose and set the column names with the character word extracted

```
lines <- readLines('trials.txt')
out <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(read.csv(text=sub("\\S+\\s+", "", lines), 
     header = FALSE))), sub("^(\\S+).*", "\\1", lines) )
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> out
  Control Knees  Eyes
1    0.53  0.73 -0.78
2    0.36  0.31 -0.86
3    0.20  0.03 -1.35
4   -0.37 -0.29 -1.48
5   -0.60 -0.56 -1.52
6   -0.64 -0.96 -2.04
7   -0.68 -1.61 -2.83
8   -1.27    NA    NA
```

---

Or slightly easier option is to create the `,` at the first space, read with `read.csv`, and then set the names with the first column after `t`ransposing

```
out <- read.csv(text = sub("\\s+", ",", lines), header = FALSE)
out <- setNames(as.data.frame(t(out[-1])), out[[1]])
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked exactly how I wanted it.